# Solr search query

Tags: search, solr

in this code I'm searching the word 'the gimme' from the field 'name'

```
SolrQuery slrQuery = new SolrQuery("name:the gimme");
System.out.println(slrQuery.toString());
```

the result `q=name%3Athe+gimme`
so the space characters was transformed to '+', solr return the fields that have the word 'the' or 'gimme' but I need filds have only 'the gimme'

can I have a solution? Thanks.

Comment: How is the field "name" defined in the Solr schema?

Comment: <field name="name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

and in 'text_general' I use : 
<tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to decide between search and "phrased search".
If you like to match the exact term `the gimme`you have to use phrased search.
How this works depends on the query parser, you are using.
Try:

```
SolrQuery slrQuery = new SolrQuery("name:\"the gimme\"");
```